# Linear Regression from a .csv file in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression, data-science

Can someone explain how to make a scatter plot and linear regression from an excel file?

I know how to import the the file with pandas, I know how to do a scatter plot by plugging in my own data in matplotlib, but I don't know how to make python do all three from the file.

Ideally it would also give r value, p value, std error, slope and intercept.

I'm very new to all of this and any help would be great.

I've searched around stack overflow, reddit, and else where, but I haven't found anything recent.

Comment: Can you share any of the relevant code you have written?

Comment: @ScottHunter     data=pd.read_csv('WeatherData.csv') to import my csv file. then     plt.hist(data_sample, bins=50, color='#01804f', alpha=.7, rwidth=1)
    plt.title('Sample of All')
    plt.xlabel('Rainfall Amount')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency') SO my question is how I can change this to a scatter plot and do a linear regression? i know I need     plt.scatter but I'm not totally sure where to go after that. EDIT: I'm not entirely sure why it isn't formatting the code blocks properly, or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

SciPy has a basic linear regression function that fits your criteria: [scipy.stats.linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) Just use the appropriate columns from your DataFrame as `x` and `y`.

Pyplot's basic `plt.plot(x, y)` function will give you a line: [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). You can compute a set of `y` values using the slope and intercept.